# Where can I find the roster formats of various airlines?

Tags: datasets

I discovered a mobile app called roster minder for android. It seems that the app can import rosters from various airlines. I was wondering how that was possible? Is there a standard format for crew rosters or do airlines publish roster formats, which can be consumed by the app?

Comment: I know that there are third party applications that helps airlines create their rosters, so there would at least be identical formats between airlines that use the same program.

Comment: They likely import a calendar event format (e.g. [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)).